# Why does std::iterator not contain std::prev() as a member function?

Tags: c++, iterator, std, member-functions, non-member-functions

```
it++;                       // OK    : Widely used expression for moving iterator.

it_prev = it-1;             // ERROR : What I expected; + - operators never existed
it_prev = std::prev(it)     // OK

it_next3 = it+3;            // ERROR : also, nothing like this exists
it_next3 = std::next(it,3)  // OK
```

Why does the Iterator class not have + - operators as member functions?

Or `std::prev()` as a member function to do this?

```
it_prev = it.prev()         // nothing like this
```

Is there a special reason for defining the `prev` function external to the iterator?

Comment: `next` corresponds to `+`...

Comment: `it+1` and `it+3` are valid for **random access** iterators, but not for weaker types of iterators.

Comment: @Marc Glisse   my confusion over prev() / next() is fixed. thanks for your comment

Answer (score 5):

If `prev()` were a *member function* instead of a *free function*, it would be less generic since it won't be possible to work with *built-in types* (e.g., pointers) as iterators:

```
int *ptr = ...
// ...
ptr.prev() // <-- Pointers don't have member functions!!
```

whereas with a *non-member function template*, such as `std::prev()`, all is needed for it to work with pointers is a specialization that deals with pointers:

```
int *ptr = ...
// ...
std::prev(ptr); // <-- OK
```

Pointers also support the *increment* and *decrement* operators (i.e., `++` and `--`), so defining them in iterator classes doesn't hinder generic programming. The same reasoning applies to the binary operators `+` and `-`.

Answer (score 2):

Random access iterators do have `operator+` overloaded. But others don't since something like `it + n` would have a linear complexity and most people don't expect that, especially considering iterators are also meant to be pointer-like for STL containers. That is also the reason why they don't have a member function called `prev` since pointers being valid iterator implementations is very convenient, efficient and desired.
If you want to advance the iterator and don't mind the complexity, you can do that explicitly with [`std::advance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance):

> ## std::advance
>
> [...]
>
> Increments given iterator it by n elements.
>
> If n is negative, the iterator is decremented. In this case, InputIt
> must meet the requirements of [*LegacyBidirectionalIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator), otherwise
> the behavior is undefined.
>
> [...]
>
> ## Complexity
>
> Linear.
> However, if InputIt additionally meets the requirements of
> [*LegacyRandomAccessIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator), complexity is constant.

Comment: Seems like I got perfect answer with 眠りネロク's and your answer mixed.